# Deployed Angular app sending request to Node.js backend is throwing an error

Tags: node.js, angular

This is what I see if I send request to the backend, I am using Angular 12:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://commapps.herokuapp.com/auth' from origin 'https://ecstatic-engelbart-897f34.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

ERROR Em {headers: dm, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://commapps.herokuapp.com/auth", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: And do you think your backend _does_ set the right `Access-Control-` headers for a request from that origin? In the absence of a [mre], what do you expect us to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120309/14369396)? Perhaps try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311658/14369396) provided.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed from the backend side. They have to whitelist the port number that you are using, most probable 4200.

Comment: How to whitelist the port number that I am using?

Comment: The OP's origin doesn't include a port. If you're using the Angular dev server (which defaults to port 4200) in production... _don't_.

Comment: It should go somethinglike
CORS_ALLOW_WHITELIST = (
portnumber1,
portnumber2
)